# Random function generator C++

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate a random number in C++ based on known distribution.

Here is the problem. I rolled a dice (say) 6 times, and I record a four for 3 times, and an one for 1 times, and a two for 2 times.
So four=3/6, one=1/6, two=2/6

Is there a library function that I could use which generates a random number based on the above distribution?

---

If not, do you think it is valid for me to simply do

```
int i= ran()%5;
if (i is in the range of 0 to 2)
{
  //PICK FOUR
}

else if (i is in the range of 3 to 4)
{
  // PICK ONE
}

else 
{
   // PICK TWO
}
```

Comment: For the distribution you are talking about, you want `ran()%6`.

Comment: I recommend reading these two links: http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/probability/damage-rolls.html , http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: This might be a little bit above your level, but if you want a very good random number use the WinAPI function CryptGenRandom(). It will generate loads of bytes, go through them looking just for numeric characters. Might be overkill and difficult though so I'll put this as a comment rather than an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @k1308517 Definitely overkill, and not portable (assumes OP is using Windows).

Comment: @k1308517: What is the purpose of "looking just for numeric characters"?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf He clearly stated he wanted a random number. CryptGenRandom creates a load of bytes which are alphanumeric. So, you want the numbers not the letters... Example: aSdafswed87328ehshdy27r2   from that the numbers are 87328272.

Comment: "function generator"??

Comment: @k1308517: Don't do that, and please don't teach it. Use the bytes as you get them. That's what they're for.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The bytes are characters, some characters are for letters, others for numbers etc... I'm saying just get the numbers.

Comment: @k1308517: No, the bytes are not characters. They're values in the range 0 through 255.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`std::discrete_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf A byte when converted could be the letter 'W' another could be number '3'. How am I mistaken?

Comment: @k1308517 Sorry, but you are completely wrong. A byte is a byte, you don't need to sift through them to find one that happens to match a base10 ascii digit. *All* bytes are numbers even if they don't convert to characters. They are *not meant to be*.

Comment: @k1308517: The bytes are not intended to be interpreted as character codes.

Comment: Saying dogmas without explaining the underlying thinking is not teaching.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I think the intended parse is "random function" generator. Something that generates a function that produces pseudo-random numbers. Yes?

Comment: This is a very ill-conceived question.  If you rolled a 6-sided die to get outcomes, the set of outcomes you got is a *realization* of the distribution.  It is **not** the distribution!  Were you to continue rolling, the probability of getting a 3, 5, or 6 is not zero.  If you don't think it's a fair die (equal probability of 1/6 for each of the 6 possible outcomes), and you want to get a handle on what the probabilities actually are, it will take a great deal more than 6 rolls of your die.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int pick()
 {
   static const int val[6] = { 4,4,4,1,2,2 };
   return val[ran()%6]; // <---- note %6 not %5
 }
```

**Edit** Note `ran() % 6` may or may not be uniformly distributed, even if `ran()` is. You probably want something that is guaranteed to be uniformly distributed, e.g.

```
std::random_device device;
std::default_random_engine engine(device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 5);
```

Now `dist(engine)` is a good replacement for `ran()%6`.

**Edit2** From a suggestion in the comments, here's a version based on `std::discrete_distribution`:

```
std::random_device device;
std::default_random_engine engine(device());
std::discrete_distribution<> dist ({1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0});

int pick()
{
   return dist(engine) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for simplicity, but readers should note it doesn't scale.

Comment: `static const int`?

Comment: @n.m. Re the statistical randomness problem, Knuth's old advice is to divide by a suitable small constant before taking the remainder. Because it's the least significant bits that typically are measurably non-random.